# IntelliJ: Some classes have changed message

Tags: intellij-idea

The following message is shown with regards to the SlottingTest2 file:

[image]

I know I have not changed any other file than SlottingTest2.java (at least not intentionally). So what does this message mean, and what might trigger it? Could it be referring to changes others have made in an upstream Git repo?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You probably have a debug session running. After you have updated and recompiled (possibly automatically) your file , Intellij suggests to reload the updated version of your .class into your debugging session.

To get rid of the warning, you can either make it automatic or disabled using the following setting:

[image: Configure HotSwap reload]